# Sites API should include a site branding color, or if it shouldn't, why not?

Tags: feature-request, design, api

I'm making a Stack Exchange app, and one thing I found pretty cool in the sites API is that it sends us the colors for links and tags, so my apps color is kind of consistent with the sites.

But the site branding color, like orange in Stack Overflow, or red in Server Fault, is not included. I consider that color to be the most important one, so I could use as an "accent color" in my app.

I'm thinking that maybe somebody already thought that, and maybe there is a reason to not to provide this color, but I can't think of one. If that's the case, I really want to know the reason.

P.S.: my app is a personal project to learn Jetpack Compose - https://github.com/vitor-ramos/LiveQuestions

Comment: You can get everything you need from https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/

Comment: Isn't that just for javascript? I'm making an Android app. And it looks like it's just for stack overflow.

Comment: It's the complete css framework used on all the sites, not just javascript

Comment: All sites? Even the link is stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this color is used in the side menu:

[image] [image]

So you can retrieve the site's CSS, e.g. https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/serverfault/primary.css, parse it and fetch it from the `border-right` attribute of the `.youarehere` class:

[image]

This side menu is a relative recent change, and API updates have been very rare for a couple of years.

Comment: This does solve my problem, but I believe I shouldn't rely on that to get the color. The site's devs are free to change their CSS without concerning about breaking other people's stuff, right?

Comment: It's a workaround, sure, but it's the only thing I can think of right now. I wouldn't put my hope into Stack Exchange adding this information to the API...

Comment: @VitorRamos .site-header--container background does retrieve the color.